# Помогите настроить allure

Tags: java, testng, allure

мой pom

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.6</allure.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopKey>stopjetty</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8079</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -Djava.library.path=${basedir}/lib
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlelements-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlelements-matchers</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

после команды mvn clean install site
выбрасывает error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project CnB: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Could not generate the report: Can't resolve one or more given artifacts [ru.yandex.qat
>   ools.allure:allure-bundle:jar:2.6]: Failure to find ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-bundle:jar:2.6 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updat
>   es are forced -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

если зайти на site, там есть файлик allure-maven-plugin.html и если его открыть в браузере - он пустой

Comment: надо выполнить `allure:report` вместо `site`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
<artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
<version>1.5.4</version>
```

вот это конфликтует с этим

```
<allure.version>2.6</allure.version>
```